# Detecting corrupted JPEGs: using find -exec with || logical operator

Tags: bash, find, gnu

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -exec identify -regard-warnings -verbose {} > /dev/null 2>&1 + || mv "$1" --backup=numbered {} -t "./Corrupted"
```

I'm trying to use the above to check for the existence of corrupted JPEG images in the current directory, and if they exist, move them to another directory.

As far as I can tell the issue so far is that the logic simply isn't working - nothing to the right of the `||` operator is executed at all when identify exits with a non-zero error code, even when I test with a simple `|| echo "File is bad"`.

I understand I can use a second `-exec` predicate to execute a command if the first `-exec` turns out to be true, but is there any way to execute a command if `-exec` turns out to be false?

Comment: Are you aware `{}` after `||` is just a literal `{}`? Do you want to move all files? or just bad files? Are you aware `> /dev/null 2>&1` redirect the output of `find` in the first place? I mean: not only `identify` (although it shouldn't matter here).

Comment: I was aware of the first but not the second. As for the first, I just left it in there because I knew no other way of getting the argument from the command before the `||`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can exec a `bash -c`, something like:

```
find [other parm] -exec bash -c 'identify -regard-warnings -verbose "$1" || exit 0 ; exit 1' onTheFlyScript {} \; -exec mv {} ./Corrupted \;
```

In slo-mo:

- `identify -regard-warnings -verbose "$1" || exit 0 ; exit 1` reverses the output logic of `identify` (0 if error)
- `-exec bash -c '...'  onTheFlyScript {} \;` sets `$0` to "onTheFlyScript" (ignored unless there are errors) and `$1` to your file, so it succeeds (rc=0) if the file is corrupt
- `-exec mv {} ./Corrupted \;`  is executed if the first exec succeeds so if the file is corrupt

Given the output of `identify` on good files, I would avoid the `-verbose` parm here, it only slows down the process.

Edit: simpler version, no need for the `bash -c` (which would still be unavoidable in more complex cases):

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -name '*.jpg' \( -exec identify -quiet {} \; -o -exec mv -t ./Corrupted {} \+ \)
```

In other words, the 2nd `-exec` is executed when the first fails.

As Kamil says in the comments, you cannot mass-identify the files, since you need a status for each, but you can indeed combine a `;` and a `+`, the second one is indeed executed with as many parameters as possible.

Comment: I was hoping there would be a simpler solution than spawning another shell, but thanks for the only working solution so far. This does work, but it's also pretty slow at just over 1 file a second. How would you make this work with the `exec... +` syntax to make it run a little faster? I tried a simple swap of the `\;`s with `+` and `\+` but the command fails with *"missing argument to -exec"*.

Comment: @Hashim Without inner shells it may be `find . -maxdepth 1 -type f ! -exec identify -regard-warnings {} \; -exec mv -t ./Corrupted {} +`. Not tested. There are reasons not to use `-exec … +` with `identify`; one reason: you want to test each file separately, not all of them with a *single* exit status. But I think you can use `+` with the final `mv`. It's not an answer because: (1) not tested, (2) no time for high quality answer now.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski Couldn't make the `!` solution to work, but this made me figure out a simpler solution, see edited answer.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski Both of your latest commands fail - I'm guessing this is something to do with the `mv` command as that's the only thing that's still failing. I first thought `{}` was in the wrong place but moving it to right after `mv` then causes a *missing argument to exec* error.

Comment: @Hashim How does `mv` fail exactly? Is `-t` the problem? It is not portable but you used it in the question first, so I assumed your `mv` supports the option. Or is it something else?

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski Works for me...  (must have missed something earlier). OP has put the `gnu` tag so we can assume Gnu coreutils...

Comment: Here is what I have so far: `find -maxdepth 1 -iname "*.jpg" -exec identify -regard-warnings -verbose > /dev/null {} \; -o -exec mv --backup=numbered -t "./Corrupted" {} \+`. `verbose` and I believe `regard-warnings` also are required to detect the warnings in my data set, and doing `> /dev/null` is necessary to show only the errors from the verbose output. This command works to print the errors for corrupted images, but it does not actually move any of them.

Comment: Here's a few seconds of output from the above command: https://pastebin.com/D3n9kNnR.

Comment: You are missing the `!`... What is the purpose of printing the warnings? The return code of identify doesn't depend on that...

Comment: @xenoid I'm using your latest command, which along with Kamil's, doesn't work - both of them fail to move the files. I am using GNU and `-t` is supported. I'm printing the warnings for my own benefit because I want to be able to see them, but I don't think that's what's going wrong here as I've tried both with and without.

Comment: In my command with `-o` there are escaped parenthses (`\(` and `\)`) that I don't see in the command you use (if that is the one if the comments above).

Answer (score 1):

I finally managed to figure out a version of the shorter commands given by *Kamil* and *xenoid* that actually works. I mainly did this by moving the `{}` to before the `-t` option, although with the `exec... +` syntax this also results in the following error:

> find: missing argument to `-exec'

I therefore also had to switch to using the `exec... \;` syntax, which then finally results in the following working command:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -iname "*.jpg" ! -exec identify -regard-warnings -verbose > /dev/null {} \; -exec mv {} -t ./Corrupted \;
```

The `-regard-warnings` switch to `identify` is needed to make sure that warnings  exit as non-zero in addition to errors (which is necessary to move those corrupted images that only flag warnings), and the `-verbose` switch is needed to print the warnings and errors to the screen. If you want to see no output at all, you can leave `-verbose` out.

Answer (score 0):

Using `find -exec` is easy for simple commands. But I think it's better to pipe into `| while read var; do ...cmd1 $var; cmd2 "$var"; cmd3;...stuff...; done` for more advanced stuff:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f | while read f; do identify "$f" > /dev/null 2>&1 || mv --backup=numbered "$f" ./Corrupted; done
```

Answer (score -1):

Try to use parentises:

```
(find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -exec identify -regard-warnings -verbose {} > /dev/null 2>&1 +) || mv "$1" --backup=numbered {} -t "./Corrupted"
```